# html form full width for select element

Tags: css, forms, mailchimp

I'm trying to set an (mailchimp) email-signup-form and all form elements should have full width. I need to set all the styling inside the html code (external css file is not possible). 
I'm trying to get all elements to full width, but for any reason the select element and my button do not have full width (but "nearly" full width). Can someone explain the reason or even show a solution on how to get these elements to the same size as the rest?

Thanks!

(Some parts of the form are in german.)

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup"><form id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" action="" method="post" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" target="_blank">
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

<div class="mc-field-group"><label for="mce-EMAIL"><h1>Email</h1></label>
  <input id="mce-EMAIL" class="required email" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.5em 0.2em; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 1.5em; line-height: 1.5em; border: 1px solid #606060; box-shadow: none; background: #ffffff;" type="email" name="EMAIL" value="" /></div>

<p><div class="mc-field-group"><label for="mce-SALUTATION"><h1>Anrede</h1></label>
  <select id="mce-SALUTATION" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.5em 0.2em; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 1.5em; line-height: 1.5em; border: 1px solid #606060; box-shadow: none; background: #ffffff;" name="SALUTATION">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Frau">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Herr">Mr.</option>
    </select></div>

<p><div class="mc-field-group"><label for="mce-FNAME"><h1>Vorname</h1> </label>
  <input id="mce-FNAME" type="text" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.5em 0.2em; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 1.5em; line-height: 1.5em; border: 1px solid #606060; box-shadow: none;" name="FNAME" value="" /></div>


<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input tabindex="-1" type="text" name="b_8f44437b2b26a07918f0d32dd_afef57f14e" value="" /></div>

<div><input id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.5em 0.2em; margin-top: 1.05em; margin-bottom: 1.5em; line-height: 1.5em; border: 1px solid #606060; shadow: none; background: #790000; color: #ffffff;" type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Jetzt Anmelden" /></div>
</div>
</form></div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup"><form id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" action="" method="post" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" target="_blank">
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

<div class="mc-field-group"><label for="mce-EMAIL"><h1>Email</h1></label>
  <input id="mce-EMAIL" class="required email" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.5em 0.2em; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 1.5em; line-height: 1.5em; border: 1px solid #606060; box-shadow: none; background: #ffffff;box-sizing:border-box" type="email" name="EMAIL" value="" /></div>

<p><div class="mc-field-group"><label for="mce-SALUTATION"><h1>Anrede</h1></label>
  <select id="mce-SALUTATION" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.5em 0.2em; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 1.5em; line-height: 1.5em; border: 1px solid #606060; box-shadow: none; background: #ffffff;box-sizing:border-box" name="SALUTATION">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Frau">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Herr">Mr.</option>
    </select></div>

<p><div class="mc-field-group"><label for="mce-FNAME"><h1>Vorname</h1> </label>
  <input id="mce-FNAME" type="text" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.5em 0.2em; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 1.5em; line-height: 1.5em; border: 1px solid #606060; box-shadow: none;box-sizing:border-box" name="FNAME" value="" /></div>


<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input tabindex="-1" type="text" name="b_8f44437b2b26a07918f0d32dd_afef57f14e" value="" /></div>

<div><input id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.5em 0.2em; margin-top: 1.05em; margin-bottom: 1.5em; line-height: 1.5em; border: 1px solid #606060; shadow: none; background: #790000; color: #ffffff;box-sizing:border-box" type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Jetzt Anmelden" /></div>
</div>
</form></div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Comment: problem is not with <select> it is with <input>. You have used padding, so making this 100% total width is increase (100% + padding). use box-sizing:border-box